# SHOW GRANTS displays there is no such grant defined for user

Tags: mysql

I have a user that is currently running my MySQL database. I wanted to see the rights that user has by executing the following:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'localhost';
```

and I got

```
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'myuser' on host 'localhost'
```

Shouldn't I see some permissions for that user since it's currently being used to read/write>

*Edit:* When I run the following query to see the hostname associated with the user, it returns `%` as the host.

```
select host from mysql.user where user = 'myuser';
```

Comment: Maybe the hostname in his grant is the name or address of your server, not `localhost`. Use `select host from mysql.user where user = 'myuser';` to see the hostnames in his accounts.

Comment: I ran that statement it displays '%' what does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hostname `%` is a wildcard meaning any host. So to see his grants, do:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myuser'@'%';
```

Answer (score 2):

To see the rights of the currently logged in use it should be suffient with just [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-grants.html)

To find the hosts and wild cards used for a user run `select Host from mysql.user where User = 'myuser';`, Then use that host (and user) to run `SHOW GRANTS FOR myuser@<host>`

Comment: That works, however I'm having issues looking up GRANT rights for another user.